# How do I highlight (select) text in Text widget with a button click?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, widget

I'm using Tkinter 8.5 and Python 3.3, and I would like my users to be able to copy the text in a Text widget on the click of a button. I've got that part working, but I also wanted to display this visually to the user by highlighting (selecting) the text as well.

**Here is some sample code:**

```
from tkinter import *

def copy():
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(entry.get(0.0, END))
    entry.select_all() # though I wish it did, this attribute doesn't exist!

root = Tk()

entry = Text(root)
entry.pack()

button = Button(root, text="Copy your text", command=copy)
button.pack()
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
entry.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
```

or

```
entry.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end-1c')
```